# Why is the text font in the Microsoft sign in website weird?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, text, microsoft

I'm using Chrome in this screenshot. When I try to log into Outlook on the web, the login screen uses a weird font. Why is this the case? Can I change it?

[image]

Comment: maybe you don't have that font on your computer!

Comment: Do you know what font it is and how I would get it?

Comment: It looks (similar) to that on my PC in Chrome but uses a different font when I use Firefox.